# use excel data to register for a website in selenium

Tags: java, excel, insert, selenium-webdriver, html

how to read data from an excel sheet and use that data as an input to a webpage using `selenium` ?

This is the code I am using to read data from the excel sheet

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class DataDriven {

public void readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException{

        String FilePath = "D:\\sampledoc.xls";
         FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
         Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

         //TO get the access to the sheet
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet2");

        // To get the number of rows present in sheet
        int rows = sh.getRows();

        // To get the number of columns present in sheet
        int cols = sh.getColumns();

        for(int row=0; row<sh.getRows(); row++)
        {
            System.out.print(sh.getCell(0,0).getContents());
            System.out.print(":::");
            System.out.println(sh.getCell(1,1).getContents());
        }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws BiffException, IOException
{
    DataDriven DT = new DataDriven();
    DT.readExcel();
}
```

But how do I use this read data as input to a web page?

Answer (score 0):

You should first store your user-password combinations in a local object, like a Map.
Then you need to provide accessors to that Map.
It can be a simple `get()`, or something like `get(int index)`, or however you would like to access the data.
In your selenium testcases, you then have to call that accessor method and then use the returned values in your textfield write operation.

Depending on your reqirements, you can or should implement the data provider thread-safe or as singlton, or as simple object you instanciate. Whatever fits your needs best.

Edit:
If you think about instanciating the object everytime you need it, think about performance for reading the excel sheet. I never did that before, so I don't know how performant it is. But you might want to convert the excelsheet into a simple CSV file before using it.

Comment: "driver.findElement(By.name("firstname").sendkeys(sh.getCell(0,0),sh.getContents());"
Would this work? Is it absolutely necssary to create a map?

Comment: If you don't store the data in a Map or in any other internal storage, you would have to read the Excel-File every time you need data. If that is OK for you, you can do it.


Your code should be more like this:
`String name = sh.getCell(0,0);
String pw = sh.getCell(0,1);
driver.findElement(By.name("firstname").sendkeys(name);
driver.findElement(By.name("password").sendkeys(pw);`

Comment: So , say i have an excel sheet with 10 rows of data . I use
 
"String name = sh.getCell(0,0); String pw = sh.getCell(0,1); driver.findElement(By.name("firstname").sendkeys(name); driver.findElement(By.name("password").sendkeys(pw);"within a loop ,will it do the same work for all the 10 rows?

Comment: A loop with exactly that code would be useless as the getCell(0,0) and getcell(0,1) will always fetch the first entry from the Excelsheet.
Use the Loop-Index to go through the lines in the Excel:
`for(int index = 0; index < MAX_ITTERATIONS; ++index)`
and then
`sh.getCell(index,0);` and `sh.getCell(index,1);`

Comment: I have to read the data from an excel file and click the corresponding radio button on a web page .. 
"String sex = sh.getCell(index,2).toString();
driver.findElement(By.name("sex")).click(sex);" i used this , is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work.
The parameter of the click() method, is a locator. But you already defined the location by the findElement(By.name()).
Try, if it works. But if not, try only `selenium.click(sex);`, as long as the value of `sex` is a location.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for read data from excel sheet and using that data register into website...

```
public void readExcel() throws IOException{
 WebDriver driver = null;
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\testproject\\ExcelDemo.xlsx";
String fileName = "ExcelDemo.xlsx";
String sheetName = "Sheet1";

//Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

Workbook workbook = null;

//Find the file extension by spliting file name in substring and getting only extension name

String fileExtensionName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

//Check condition if the file is xlsx file

if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){

//If it is xlsx file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

}

//Check condition if the file is xls file

else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){

    //If it is xls file then create object of XSSFWorkbook class

    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

}

//Read sheet inside the workbook by its name

Sheet guru99Sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

//Find number of rows in excel file

int rowCount = guru99Sheet.getLastRowNum()-guru99Sheet.getFirstRowNum();

//Create a loop over all the rows of excel file to read it
System.out.print(rowCount);

for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {

    Row row = guru99Sheet.getRow(i);
    System.out.print(row.getLastCellNum());

    //Create a loop to print cell values in a row

    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        if(j==0){
            driver.get("webpage name");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(row.getCell(j).toString());
        }
        else{
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(row.getCell(j).toString());
        }
        //Print excel data in console
        row.getCell(j).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        System.out.print(row.getCell(j)+"|| ");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
driver.close();
}
```